# angular and Cloudinary direct upload 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cloudinary

i'm getting a `400 bad request` error when trying to upload to cloudinary with the following code:

```
var file = /* your file */;
var cloud_name = 'your cloud_name';

var fd = new FormData();

fd.append('upload_preset', 'seller');
fd.append('file', file);

$http
    .post('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/' + cloud_name + '/image/upload', fd, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': application/x-www-form-urlencoded,
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        }
    })
    .success(function (cloudinaryResponse) {

        // do stuff with cloudinary response
        // cloudinaryResponse = { public_id: ..., etc. }

    })
    .error(function (reponse) {


    });
```

What am I missing? Is it possible to do a Cloudinary direct upload?

Comment: 'Content-Type': undefined ? Why did you mention Content-Type as undefined?

Comment: @Sujith Thanks for reply. "Application / x-www-form-urlencoded" does not work either.

Comment: Can you try to change to `multipart/form-data`? Also, share the `X-Cld-Error` message (returned in the response).